# Growth (sales) forecast based on season

Tags: predictive-modeling, forecasting, data-analysis

How to make a forecast based on last year (season)?

I have no experience in the field

Make a forecast of the sales in september 2023 based on last years sales

## Example A

- Sales august 2022 (last year): **12**
- Sales september 2022 (last year): **17**
- Sales august 2023 (this year): **21**

The way I *think* it should be done is by calculating the growth for last year and then apply that to this year

Growth september 2022 (last year) = 17/12 = **1.42**

Forecast september 2023 (this year) = 21*1.42 = **29.82**

## Example B

- Sales august 2022 (last year): **2**
- Sales september 2022 (last year): **0**
- Sales august 2023 (this year): **31**

How to calculate this one if the forecast month last year was **0**? If you look at the growth from august 2022 to august 2023 it gained ~1500%

## Example C

- Sales august 2022 (last year): **0**
- Sales september 2022 (last year): **2**
- Sales august 2023 (this year): **31**

How to calculate this one? The growth is more or less infinite going from 0 to 2 last year and going from 0 to 31 this year